# form calculator check box for 10% extra - how to uncheck box and 10%

Tags: javascript, forms, checkbox, calculator

I've used an old adobe Dreamweaver extension called form calculator by Kaosweaver. it made a basic form calculator for me and it works by the customer stating the total number of square meters of tiles they need. The result is the total number of tiles needed for that area.

I then added a checkbox so the customer can add 10% to the total amount onclick.

However, onclick isn't the same as true and false and when the customer unchecks the checkbox it is seen as a new onclick and adds another 10% instead of removing the first 10%.

> (10% is actually *1.1 in the calculation).

Can someone please tell me how I should have the code so the checkbox performs the way I intend it to work.

```js
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p, i, x;
  if (!d) d = document;
  if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
    d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
    n = n.substring(0, p);
  }
  if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
  for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++)
    x = d.forms[i][n];
  for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++)
    x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
  if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
  return x;
}

function KW_getVal(o) { //v1.2
  var retVal = "0";
  if (o.type == "select-one") {
    retVal = (o.selectedIndex == -1) ?
      0 : o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;
  } else if (o.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
      if (o[i].checked) retVal = o[i].value;
  } else if (o.type == "checkbox") {
    retVal = (o.checked) ? o.value : 0;
  } else {
    retVal = Number(o.value)
  }
  return parseFloat(retVal);
}

function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
  var str = "",
    a = KW_calcForm.arguments;
  for (var i = 3; i < a.length; i++)
    str += (a[i].indexOf("#") == -1) ? a[i] : KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
  t = Math.ceil(a[1] * eval(str)) / a[1];
  tS = t.toString();
  if (a[2] > 0) {
    tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    if (tSp == -1) tS += ".";
    tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    while (tSp != (tS.length - 1 - a[2])) {
      tS += "0";
      tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    }
  }
  MM_findObj(a[0]).value = tS;
}
```

```html
<h3>Tile Calculator</h3>
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
  <p> <label 
  onclick="KW_calcForm('number of tiles',1,-1,'#squaremeters','*','50')">square meters                       <input name="square meters" type="text" id="squaremeters"             
  onkeyup="KW_calcForm('number of tiles',1,-1,'#squaremeters','*','50')" />
            </label>
  </p>
  <p>
    <label>number of tiles
            <input type="text" name="number of tiles" id="numberoftiles" 
             readonly />
              </label>
  </p>

  <p><strong>Remember! We always recommend to add 10% extra for cuts</strong></p>


  <input name="10pecent" type="checkbox" id="myCheck" 
  onClick="KW_calcForm('number of tiles',1,-1,'#numberoftiles','*','1.1')" value="plus10percent"> <label>add 10% extra to total.</label>

</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the site a metafield {{ product.metafields.cal.sqm }} would be used instead of the number 50 but for this example Ive used the number.

```js
function MM_findObj(n, d) { //v4.01
  var p, i, x;
  if (!d) d = document;
  if ((p = n.indexOf("?")) > 0 && parent.frames.length) {
    d = parent.frames[n.substring(p + 1)].document;
    n = n.substring(0, p);
  }
  if (!(x = d[n]) && d.all) x = d.all[n];
  for (i = 0; !x && i < d.forms.length; i++)
    x = d.forms[i][n];
  for (i = 0; !x && d.layers && i < d.layers.length; i++)
    x = MM_findObj(n, d.layers[i].document);
  if (!x && d.getElementById) x = d.getElementById(n);
  return x;
}

function KW_getVal(o) { //v1.2
  var retVal = "0";
  if (o.type == "select-one") {
    retVal = (o.selectedIndex == -1) ?
      0 : o.options[o.selectedIndex].value;
  } else if (o.length > 1) {
    for (var i = 0; i < o.length; i++)
      if (o[i].checked) retVal = o[i].value;
  } else if (o.type == "checkbox") {
    retVal = (o.checked) ? o.value : 0;
  } else {
    retVal = Number(o.value)
  }
  return parseFloat(retVal);
}

function KW_calcForm() { //v1.2
  var str = "",
    a = KW_calcForm.arguments;
  for (var i = 3; i < a.length; i++)
    str += (a[i].indexOf("#") == -1) ? a[i] :
    KW_getVal(MM_findObj(a[i].substring(1)));
  t = Math.ceil(a[1] * eval(str)) / a[1];
  tS = t.toString();
  if (a[2] > 0) {
    tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    if (tSp == -1) tS += ".";
    tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    while (tSp != (tS.length - 1 - a[2])) {
      tS += "0";
      tSp = tS.indexOf(".");
    }
  }
  MM_findObj(a[0]).value = tS;
}
```

```html
<form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">


  <div class="product-form--atc-qty form-fields--qty" data-quantity- wrapper="">

    <div class="form-field form-field--qty-input">


      <input class="form-field-input form-field-number form-field-filled" value="" type="text" pattern="\d*" name="square meters" type="text" id="squaremeters" onkeyup="KW_calcForm('quantity',1,-1,'#square meters','*','50')" />
      <label class="form-field-title">Sq metres</label>

    </div>

  </div>

</form>
<form>

  <input name="id" value="{{ product.variants[0].id }}" type="hidden">


  <div class="product-form--atc">
    <div class="product-form--atc-qty form-fields--qty">

      <div class="form-field form-field--qty-input">
        <input class="form-field-input form-field-number form-field-filled" value="0" id="Quantity" name="quantity" type="text" pattern="\d*" onkeyup="KW_calcForm('square meters',10,-1,'#Quantity','/','50')" aria-label="{{ 'general.general.quantity' | t }}" data-quantity-input>
        <label class="form-field-title">Quantity</label>

      </div>


    </div>


  </div>




</form>
<p>
```

Comment: I could not quickly find an elegant solution to having the checkbox. I am not sure if you posted this as an answer - you should not use answers to elaborate on updates

Comment: thank you for looking at this for me. sorry I didn't know who to add this updated code as a comment and not an answer.